# Input Range.Address into a formula without ' '

Tags: excel, vba

Appreciate if anyone can help me out,

There are 2 Questions

**Question1:**

I have a VBA which should prompt an input box, allow user to select a cell and return the address into a vlookup formula. However, the cell will return the ' ' sign with the address

This is the actual result  `=IFNA(VLOOKUP('J1242','D:\Users\[file.xlsm]Working'!$A:$BG,15,0),"")`

This is what I want `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(J1242,'D:\Users\[file.xlsm]Working'!$A:$BG,15,0),"")`

```
    Set myCell = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
        
        MsgBox myCell.Address
        
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(" & myCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & ",'D:\Users\[file.xlsm]Working'!C1:C59,15,0),"""")"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

**Question2:**

Why does it return `=IFNA(VLOOKUP('J1242','D:\Users\[file.xlsm]Working'!$A:$BG,15,0),"")`

when my code shows:

```
"=IFNA(VLOOKUP(" & myCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & ",'D:\Users\[file.xlsm]Working'!C1:C59,15,0),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

I type in the formula using a macro recorder.

Comment: Maybe use   Replace(myCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), "'", "")

Comment: `Address` defaults to A1 format, not R1C1.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address   You need to provide the `ReferenceStyle` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this returns an A1 formatted address

```
myCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

but your formula `.FormulaR1C1` is in R1C1 format.

So instead of `.FormulaR1C1` you need to use `.Formula` which is A1 format. They both need to match in their format.